# In Javascript, how do I obtain a gridview's current page index?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that adds an onclick attribute whenever a row is created. As part of the Javascript method, I attached the following code:

```
alert('<%=gvxTaskList.PageIndex%>');
```

But no matter what page I click on, the alert always returns 0 instead of the current page's index. How do I, through Javascript, obtain the current page index each time a new page is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

Gridview renders as an html table.  Javascript knows nothing about GridViews.

You can put the page index in a hidden control and read that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for getting the current page index:-

```
<code> 
   var CurrentIndexOfPage= Grid1.get_currentPageIndex(); 
</code>
```

Comment: Says that the gridview contains no definition for get_currentPageIndex().

Comment: I have just written a piece. I think @Steve Wellens has written what I wanted to explain through this.